# Display Fetch Error Message on UI in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch-api

How can I display the error message on m HTML/UI? Currently, it displays the error message in my console, but It should be displayed on the data div.

Currently, when there's an error, nothing is displayed on the UI, just the console.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')


.then((res) => (res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res)))


.then((result) => {


if (Array.isArray(result)) {


results.append(result);


}else {


result.forEach((item) => {


data.append((item));


});
}
}
)
.catch(console.error);

}
```

Comment: you can use [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

Comment: @matanh I want it displayed where the results would have been displayed, instead of a pop up

Comment: can you share the html? (to know where the results should be)